# Haskell Inferred/Explicit Types of Where Bindings

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to write a function that compares the lists of degrees of the nodes in two given graphs for a sufficiency test of isomorphism, but I noticed the following code throws errors related to the type of `degs`:

```
import Data.List

degreeNumbers :: (Eq a) => Graph a -> [Int]
degreeNumbers g = ...

isoByDegree :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Graph a -> Graph b -> Bool
isoByDegree g1 g2 = degs g1 == degs g2
        where degs = sort . degreeNumbers
```

Even when I try to bind `degs` with an explicit declaration like

```
where degs = (sort . degreeNumbers) :: (Eq c) => Graph c -> [Int]
```

it still says it's expecting a type of `Graph a` rather than `Graph b` upon being applied to `g2`. Of course, there's the plain solution of

```
isoByDegree g1 g2 = (sort . degreeNumbers) g1 == (sort . degreeNumbers) g2
```

but I'm wondering what's going wrong with the binding approach.

Comment: These MR issues appear so frequently here on SO that I think GHC should at least warn about them by default (assuming that turning off MR by default is undesirable). E.g. on a type error, if the expression contains some monomorphically inferred terms, GHC should output a warning about them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the dreaded [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). Disable it with `NoMonomorphismRestriction`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Data.List

type Graph a = [a]

degreeNumbers :: (Eq a) => Graph a -> [Int]
degreeNumbers g = undefined

isoByDegree :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Graph a -> Graph b -> Bool
isoByDegree g1 g2 = degs g1 == degs g2
        where degs = sort . degreeNumbers
```

If you don't want to disable the monomorhism restriction, you can give the declaration for `degs` an explicit signature.

```
isoByDegree :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Graph a -> Graph b -> Bool
isoByDegree g1 g2 = degs g1 == degs g2
        where
            degs :: (Eq c) => Graph c -> [Int]
            degs = sort . degreeNumbers
```

Adding a signature to the right hand side of the declaration only gives the expression on the right hand side an explicit type (which is the same as what would be inferred); it doesn't make the `degs` declaration polymorphic.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions are insightful. Just when I thought I'd come across all the obscure stumbling blocks in the domain of my basic applications!

Answer (score 2):

Because you're giving a type declaration to the right-hand-side of the equation, rather than the left, Haskell still uses type inference to figure out the type of `degs`. And because of the monomorphism restriction, it will only infer a monomorphic type for something that doesn't "look" like a function. The fix is to explicitly annotate the thing you are naming, rather than the value you are giving to its name:

```
isoByDegree :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Graph a -> Graph b -> Bool
isoByDegree g1 g2 = degs g1 == degs g2
  where degs :: (Eq c) => Graph c -> [Int]
        degs = sort . degreeNumbers
```